# How to add an image to a column that is contained in only one column?

Tags: html, css

The requirements are that there must be 3 columns, have a 2em gap between them, be 200px each, a line between them using column-rule, and image that is contained in only one of the columns.

http://jsfiddle.net/nxvtew0a/

```
    <body>

<div class="columnz">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sed porttitor erat. Maecenas in lacus risus. In in vehicula lacus. Integer tellus massa, sollicitudin eu tempor sed, sodales in urna. Curabitur ultricies id neque at tempus. Duis vehicula libero iaculis, iaculis est vitae, volutpat odio. Maecenas blandit tellus sed malesuada auctor. Pellentesque sit amet quam accumsan, sagittis est a, bibendum risus. Sed viverra ante vitae enim vulputate venenatis. </p>
<img src="http://tinyurl.com/nonzzfy" alt="interstellar">
    <p>In congue sapien mattis erat placerat accumsan. Nullam at consectetur nibh. Nullam hendrerit nisi tortor, quis pretium nulla porttitor vitae. Maecenas accumsan finibus ligula sed auctor. Nulla eu diam eu ex consectetur facilisis. Vestibulum nec sem tellus. Phasellus eu ex tellus. Morbi facilisis interdum aliquam. Nunc pellentesque, leo sed facilisis varius, mi nibh venenatis nibh, in scelerisque nibh dui eget ipsum. Ut hendrerit laoreet augue id laoreet. Fusce rhoncus ex eget sem placerat faucibus imperdiet id metus. Suspendisse vitae sapien quis ante fermentum posuere sit amet quis felis. In vulputate at mi in eleifend. Donec auctor leo vitae tincidunt cursus. </p>

    <p>Nam vestibulum ut nunc et vulputate. Suspendisse blandit nulla accumsan magna elementum, sed efficitur tellus vulputate. Nam cursus lacus turpis. Mauris elementum faucibus facilisis. Curabitur non diam ut nibh congue venenatis eget ornare eros. Aliquam egestas justo vel cursus volutpat. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce ornare lacinia enim, at ornare elit tempor sed. Nulla venenatis molestie maximus. Sed in egestas nulla. Donec vulputate magna eu accumsan fringilla. Mauris id scelerisque ante, at dapibus risus. Morbi ligula sem, mollis vel condimentum luctus, sagittis id magna. Praesent vehicula tortor ante, nec vulputate purus venenatis consequat. Suspendisse convallis sem efficitur, malesuada leo et, mollis ipsum. </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>

    body { 
text-indent: 1em;
margin: 0px;
text-align: justify;}

.columnz {
-moz-column-count: 3;
-moz-column-gap: 32px;
-moz-column-rule: 1px solid #000; 
-moz-column-width: 200px;
-webkit-columns: 3;
-webkit-column-gap: 32px;
-webkit-column-rule: 1px solid #000;
-webkit-column-width:100px;
column-count: 3;
column-gap: 32px;
column-rule: 1px solid #000;
column-width:200px;}

.columnz img {
     -webkit-column-span: 1; 
    column-span: 1;}
```

1. Is it necessary to add the webkit/moz properties to each css rule?
2. How do you contain the img to just the 1 column? It doesn't seem to be doing anything the way I have it written.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add the following style to the CSS of your image:

```
.columnz img {
     width: 100%;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nxvtew0a/1/)

Comment: Work great. Thank you! Although the image is pushed right up against the line from the column-rule. How would i get it to have the same styling as the paragraphs?

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, you want the image to have some spacing from the top? If yes, you can add the following style to the CSS of `.columnz img`: `margin-top: 20px;`. http://jsfiddle.net/nxvtew0a/2/

Answer (score 1):

By "contain img to just the 1 column" you mean that you want it the image to fit in a single column I assume?

If so you need width: 100%;

```
.columnz img {
     -webkit-column-span: 1;
    width: 100%;
    column-span: 1;}
}
```